# How to solve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str

Tags: python

still a beginner here so pls dont judge :)

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime 
import os

Time = datetime.now()
dt_string = Time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Welcome " + os.getlogin() + " the current date and time is:" + Time)
```

anyways i get somehow then this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    print("Welcome " + os.getlogin() + " the current date and time is:" + Time)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str
```

I tried to get something like: Welcome (name) the current date and time is: (time)
How can i solve that?
i think its a easy question for others but still smt to start with for me :)

Comment: Hint: Why did you convert the time stamp with `strftime` to a string and saved it in `dt_string`?

Comment: You can simply cast the Time to string type and concat with the print statement

    
`print("Welcome " + os.getlogin() + " the current date and time is:" + str(Time))`

Answer (score 0):

print("Welcome " + os.getlogin() + " the current date and time is:" + str(Time)).
This solve your problem. Kindly check once

o/p:
Welcome XXXXX the current date and time is:2023-06-23 12:24:44.772064

Comment: Issue is in `Time`, your string casting should have happened in `Time`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime 
import os

Time = datetime.now()
dt_string = Time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(f"Welcome {os.getlogin()} the current date and time is: {dt_string}")
```